# Linear regression not converging for some datasets

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

I have created a simple implementation of Multivariate Linear Regression in Python, which works as expected. But for some particular data sets the cost function is not getting reduced no matter how many iterations or whatever the learning rate I use.

For example- for

X = [[6.2],[6.5],[5.48],[6.54],[7.18],[7.93]] (single independent variable)

Y = [26.3, 26.65, 25.03, 26.01, 27.9, 30.47]

cost function is not going below 0.24 even after 100000 iterations with learning rate 0.04.

Is there any problem with my implementation?

```
import numpy as np

'''
Linear Regression algorithm:-
feature_count - No. of independent variables.

Attributes:-
learning_rate - Set or change the learning rate of the algorithm.

Methods-
1- predict - Predict values based on provided features X.
2- cost - Find cost corresponding to features X and outputs Y.
3- train - Train the algorithm using features X and outputs Y.

Arguments of Methods-
X - Features. This should always be a 2D array, even if there is only one row.
Y - Outputs. This should always be a 1D array.
'''
class LinearRegressor:
    def __init__(self, feature_count: int, learning_rate: float):
        self.alpha = learning_rate
        self.theta = np.zeros(feature_count + 1)
        
    def predict(self, X):
        X = np.insert(X, 0, 1, axis = 1)
        return np.dot(X, self.theta)
    
    def cost(self, X, Y):
        theta = self.theta
        X = np.insert(X, 0, 1, axis = 1)
        m = X.shape[0]
        E = np.dot(X, theta) - Y
        return (1/m) * np.dot(E, E)
        
    def train(self, X, Y, iterations: int):
        dot = np.dot
        tp = np.transpose
        
        X = np.insert(X, 0, 1, axis = 1)
        alpha = self.alpha
        theta = self.theta
        m = X.shape[0]
        
        for _ in range(0, iterations):
            theta = theta - (alpha/m) * dot( tp(X), dot(X, theta)-Y )
            
        self.theta = theta
        
    @property
    def learning_rate(self):
        return self.alpha
    
    @learning_rate.setter
    def learning_rate(self, value):
        self.alpha = value
```

```
from ml_algorithms import LinearRegressor

X = [[6.2],[6.5],[5.48],[6.54],[7.18],[7.93]]
Y = [26.3, 26.65, 25.03, 26.01, 27.9, 30.47]

lr = LinearRegressor(1, 0.04)
lr.train(X, Y, 100000)
print("Theta values after training- ", lr.theta)
print("Predicting training data-    ", lr.predict(X))
print("Cost- ", lr.cost(X, Y))
```

Output-

```
Theta values after training-  [12.54939547  2.18588067]

Predicting training data-     [26.10185564 26.75761984 24.52802155 26.84505507 28.2440187  29.8834292 ]

Cost-  0.24375945142471633
```

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation seems fine. In your setup, you have only 2 learnable parameters that your model can tweak to lower the loss. You reach a limit where any further tweak (given the *precision* with which weight updates are being computed) to the value of your parameters will increase the loss.

The precision of your computations controls the granularity with which you can apply updates to your parameters. Increasing it will let you to apply more fine-grained updates to your weights.

To test the idea, you can increase the precision of your learnable parameters. Your new `__init__` function would look like so:

```
def __init__(self, feature_count: int, learning_rate: float):
    self.alpha = learning_rate
    self.theta = np.zeros(feature_count + 1, dtype=np.longdouble)
```

Running the exact same code as before gives us a loss value of `0.2437594514247159799` which is lower than your current loss value.

The decrease in loss is pretty inconsequential, but we are approaching the limits of what we can achieve without changing the implementation itself. To decrease the loss further, consider changing your implementation. Maybe use a modelling technique that has a higher learning capacity.